# protected footnotes cause hyperref error

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

To use a footnote in a section one has to use the protect keyword to avoid an error... then when using the hyperref package you get another error:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 105.
```

With MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\scrollmode


\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\section{Test Section\protect\footnote{my footnote}}
asdfasdfsadf


\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is to use optional argument for section like:

```
\section[Test section]{Test Section\footnote{my footnote}}
```

Then you don't have to protect anything.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`\texorpdfstring`](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-160004.1.2) in your section title as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\scrollmode

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\section{\texorpdfstring{Test Section\protect\footnote{my footnote}}{Test Section}}
asdfasdfsadf

\end{document}
```